# How to create a image viewer in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

There are many image viewer library in android (like [stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer)). But for now, i can not find one for compose, is it possible to achieve this by compose native api? Just want the zoom in and zoom out in another view after clicking the image.

Comment: What *exactly* does "completely achieve this" mean? You can display images in Compose -- see [the official samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples).

Comment: I have checked this, it seems there is no single image viewer to show the detail of the image, and also the image is not clickable.

Comment: To make things clickable, [use `Modifier.clickable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.String,%20androidx.compose.foundation.InteractionState,%20androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,%20kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0)).